# How to load elements into a string array

Tags: .net, vb.net, arrays, string

I have the following code to display filenames in a gridview. the variable filename contains the filenames that are present in a folder. now i want to store these filename values into a string array for further usage.

'Displaying files from a folder onto a gridview

```
   Dim inqueuePath As String = "C:\Users\Desktop\Sample" 
   Dim fileInfo() As String 
   Dim rowint As Integer = 0 
   Dim name As String 
   Dim directoryInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(inqueuePath) 
fileInfo = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(inqueuePath) 

  With TaskGrid 
    .Columns.Add("Column 0", "TaskName") 
    .AutoResizeColumns() 
 End With 

For Each name In fileInfo 
    ConfigWindow.TaskGrid.Rows.Add() 
    Dim filename As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(name) 
    ConfigWindow.TaskGrid.Item(0, rowint).Value = filename 
    rowint = rowint + 1 
Next
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: A List would be better here unless you will always have the same number on files in the folder.

Comment: `fileInfo` is a string array.

Answer (score 0):

As Stevo3000 points out in his comment, **fileInfo already is a string array**.

The `Directory.GetFiles Method (String)` returns the names of files (including their paths) in the specified directory.

You can find more details here on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As Stevo3000 points out in his comment, **fileInfo already is a string array.**

Just **declare your fileinfo() variable at module/class** level and you have your file list in array for using elsewhere

EDIT: Modify your loop

Declare fileInfo at Class level

```
Dim name as String
For i as integer = 0 To fileInfo.Length() - 1 
    name = fileinfo(i)
    ConfigWindow.TaskGrid.Rows.Add() 
    Dim filename As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(name) 
    ConfigWindow.TaskGrid.Item(0, rowint).Value = filename 
    rowint = rowint + 1
    fileinfo(i) = filename
Next
```

Comment: fileinfo() variable contains the names of files including their paths. But i need to store only filenames excluding their paths

Comment: You can use `IO.Path.GetFileName(path)` or `IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)`to extract filenames only